# How to use parameters from an output that is separated by lines, using bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I'm executing a command in a bash file that will provide me with the below sample output. I want to be able to loop through the output and execute a new command on each of the sections using some of the values as a parameters for the call. I'm not sure how to parse through each section with the "===" lines and actually get/use the parameters. I believe the solution would begin with piping the output to somewhere, but I 'm not sure how to proceed from there. Any guidance/samples would be appreciated!

```
==============================================================================
  hostName             = samplehost                                   
  port                 = 1234                                              
  id                   = 1                                                 
  serviceName          = serviceName                                           
  databaseStatus       = AVAILABLE                                         
  databaseContainerType = CONTAINER                                         
==============================================================================
  hostName             = samplehost2                                   
  port                 = 5678                                              
  id                   = 2                                                 
  serviceName          = serviceName2                                        
  databaseStatus       = UNAVAILABLE                                       
  databaseContainerType = PLUGGABLE                                         
==============================================================================
```

Comment: Do you have any context for how you are trying to use the output. Some example code may help clarify your question.